# temporarily turn off scroll in ListView

Tags: nativescript

Is there a way to turn off this behaviour and then back on? If my app detects that a user tries to swipe an item right, I want to be able to "tell" the ListView to temporarily stop scrolling so the user can complete the gesture.
In Android I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970331/android-turn-listview-scrolling-on-and-off), but I prefer finding something for both platforms at once- perhaps override the default touch handler?

Comment: Which one you using ListView or RadListView?

Comment: You're right, will be more accurate next time: it's ListView

Answer (score 1):

On iOS you may set the `scrollEnabled` property on native view to `false`.

```
listView.ios.scrollEnabled = false;
```

On Android the same solution you have linked in your question should work. You will have to extend your own version of `android.widget.ListView` then override the [createNativeView](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/list-view/list-view.android.ts#L53) callback to inject your custom ListView instead of the default one.